# Performance efficient way to calculate if Vec2 point is inside of one rectangle and not inside of another rectangle that is inside of first rectangle

Tags: geometry

I have 4 corners of each rectangle, each corner is vec2, the inner rectangle is constatly moving inside of outter rectangle, i want to be able to choose any point that is inside of big rectangle and not inside of small one, how would one do that efficiently?
[Visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eggUI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomly chose one of four compass directions: $\{E,N,W,S\}$.
Then form the corresponding rectangle.
For example, using the OP's notation,
if $S$, then $R = (y_1,y_4, x'_4, x'_1)$
where e.g. $x'_1$ is the point whose horizontal coordinate is that of $y_1$,
and whose vertical coordinate is that of $x_1$.
(Pardon the poor notation.)
This is the rectangle south of the inner rectangle.

---

[image]

---

Now chose a random point within $R$. Could weight the rectangles by area
for uniformity.

This will still over-populate the corner regions. If that matters to you, partition the portion outside the inner rectangle into $8$ regions.